# voice changer, how is made?

Tags: iphone, voice, voice-recognition

I'm looking to implement a voice changer into my iPhone app. Something a bit like Talking Friends. I have 5 different voice styles.

anyone can give a hint

any info much appreciated
thx.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no `UIDarthVaderify()` object. There's an open source project called [Skype Voice Changer](http://skypefx.codeplex.com/), it's in C# so you obviously can't use it directly in a Cocoa Touch project but you can learn how voice changing works. Essentially you're looking to change the frequency distribution of the output signal without changing the envelope that represents the phonemes being made by the speaker.